# yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue

Tags: centos, sudo

I'm trying to install sudo on Centos7.

I did like this:

```
su -
yum install sudo
```

I get this:

```
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
```

Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=container error was
14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Unknown error"

One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

```
 1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

 2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
    upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
    distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
    packages for the previous distribution release still work).

 3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
        yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

 4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
    will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
    again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

        yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
    or
        subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

 5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
    Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
    so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
    slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
    compromise:

        yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true
```

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base/7/x86_64

Comment: `Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Unknown error`. Can you post the output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `host mirrorlist.centos.org`. Looks like your Linux system is unable to resolve hostnames.

Comment: # cat /etc/resolv.conf
# This configuration is written to the config.iso
nameserver 192.168.65.1

Comment: # host mirrorlist.centos.org
-bash: host: command not found

Comment: Try `dig +short mirrorlist.centos.org`

Comment: I'm using Centos on Docker: CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
d72f653a599a        b5                  "/bin/bash"         38 minutes ago      Up 36 minutes       0.0.0.0:32769->1999/tcp   Centos7-2

Comment: 'dig' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Looks like your docker networking is not set right. How about `ping mirrorlist.centos.org`?

Comment: ping mirrorlist.centos.org
ping: mirrorlist.centos.org: Name or service not known

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107778/discussion-between-gmaster-and-dinosaur).

Comment: So your docker networking is net set right. This is not an issue with yum itself. You need to resolve the networking issue before you can install sudo

Comment: ok, thanks so much